# How to deal with null request scoped objects in Spring.NET

Tags: configuration, spring.net

I have a couple of objects in Spring.NET that I have created in the request scope.  This works fine when the instance exists but sometimes they need to be null.  If I return null from the factory that creates them I get an error from Spring.NET indicating that it cannot wrap a null object.  I gather it is trying to create a proxy around the object and failing to do so since it is null.

How do I get Spring.NET to accept a null from a factory method?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to get Spring.NET to accept a null from a factory method but maybe you can make use of the [NullObject Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in your factory method, so that your factory returns *an Object which does nothing* instead of a null reference.